# convolution-invariant subalgebra generated by $f\in L^(X)$

Tags: ergodic-theory

In the article arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1884.pdf, the author has used the language convolution-invariant subalgebra generated by $f\in L^\infty(X)$ where $X$ is a measure space, $G$  is a lcsc group and $(X,G)$ is an ergodic measure-preserving system. More precisely, he says that $L^1(G)\times L^\infty(X)\to L^\infty(X),$ $(c,f)\to c*f$ where $c*f(x):=\int_G c(g)f(g^{-1}x)dx.$ Then, "consider convolution-invariant subalgebra generated by $f\in L^\infty(X)$". What does the author actually mean by this terminology?

Comment: "convolution-invariant subalgebra generated by $f \in L^\infty(X)$" should mean "the smallest convolution-invariant subalgebra of $L^\infty(X)$ containing $f$", where "smallest" refers to inclusion (it is the case that the intersection of convolution-invariant subalgebras of $L^\infty(X)$ is a convolution-invariant subalgebra of $L^\infty(X)$). A "convolution-invariant subalgebra of $L^\infty(X)$" is a subalgebra of $L^\infty(X)$ that is convolution-invariant. A "subalgebra of $L^\infty(X)$" is a vector subspace of $L^\infty(X)$ that is closed under multiplication (i.e. an algebra). Finally,..

Comment: A subset $A$ of $L^\infty(X)$ is "convolution-invariant" if $c*h \in A$ if $c \in L^1(G)$ and $h \in A$.